# HTC Only Hard Crash inside OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, htc-android

I have been seeing this problem for a while in my application.  It shows itself by randomly hardlocking or rebooting HTC phones when they are rendering using OpenGL.  Checking the logcat it appears to be a deadlock issue as you will see this printed...

```
waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=9, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
```

The best source for information I have been able to find so far is over here:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d5b7e87f4b42fa8f/d6214ed7a02efc98?q=freeze&lnk=ol&

Where they suggest adding a glFinish at the end of your glSurface's OnDraw function.  I am not having great results using this solution (its still crashing but less often).  Has anyone else heard about this problem?  Encountered any better solutions?

Comment: This will be of little consolation, but I feel your pain. I've got 2 comments on the Market "Phone locked, had to remove battery. HTC Desire". No idea what causes this, and I've seen the game running fine on a friend's Desire.

Comment: Yea I've had it happen on a number of HTC phones but mainly during stress tests (let the app sit running overnight).  So far no solution, I do a web search every few weeks to look for updates.

Answer (score 1):

We have been getting exactly this problem on our game with HTC Sensation devices and Android 2.3.4 - so we went and bought the device and experimented for a bit. One of the solutions was to call `egl.eglWaitGL()` at the end of the `onDraw()` method but that halved the framerate - suprisingly only on that device, but I consodered it a bad solution and kept looking.

The second fix and the one we are using currently which had almost no performance penalty was to stop using `glBufferSubData` to update our vertex arrays and keep uploading the whole array with `glBufferData`. If you are using VBO's and glBufferSubData to update them, try changing it.